click element with xpath in iframe with javascript
I want to click on an element in the iframe by xpath with coding. Is there a javascript code for this?
I found this code:
    <html> <body> <iframe id="test" source="test.html"> </iframe> </body> </html>
    In scripts:
    $('#test').contents().find('BUTTON ID').click(function(){ alert("works") });
but i want to click with xpath not by id.
i want to automatically click on special element in iframe when load. not by user.
